# Library Search Part order depended on build type

Tags: ios, xcode

In my project, I contantly need to re-order the `Library Search Path` when I am switching between the iOS Simulator and the device. Since building takes a minute I would really like to find a solution on solving this automatically.

This is how my paths look now, the selected rows I need to re-order dependent on wether I launch on the device or in the simulator:

[image: Library Search Path]

Is there some way I can make xcode decide the order itself, without having to reorder them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not preferable to use multiple paths for all build styles, add only one dynamic path to Library Search Path property:

```
 - ${PROJECT_DIR}/SUPiOS/Libraries/${BUILD_STYLE}-${PLATFORM_NAME}  -- make this recursive
```

I guess now adays, ${BUILD_STYLE} is no more valid, then use below one.

```
 - ${PROJECT_DIR}/SUPiOS/Libraries/${CONFIGURATION}-${PLATFORM_NAME}  -- make this recursive
```

Once you assign this dynamic path and press enter. You can find XCode will automatically pick your folder path as per build and configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a universal binary for both simulator and the device. This would save you trouble changing/reordering the library search paths.

Its really simple to do that using `lipo`.

Here's how you can do that.

```
lipo -create libdevice.a libsimulator.a -output libuniversal.a
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am definitly going to try that in one of my own project, but for this one its not suitable since we are a large team also involving SAP devs which deliver new libs regularly.